# Upload file from android to server using OkHttp and PHP

Tags: php, android

I make Android uploader pand php script.
But I can not upload `csv` file from android local folder.

PHP sclipt can work alone.

> Error
>   Undefined index:upfile in /example/html/php/
>   uploadfile.php online 9

do not choice file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView outputText;
Button sendData;
EditText edtUser, edtPass;
final String URL = "http://example/php/uploadfile.php";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    outputText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    sendData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    edtUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edtPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    String Text = "Tue Oct 06 18:56:24 JST 2015,Tue Oct 06 18:57:12 JST 2015,35.4708118,139.6251623\n";

    try {
        OutputStream out = openFileOutput("GPS_log2.csv", MODE_APPEND);
        PrintWriter writer =
                new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
        writer.append(Text);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    sendData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            OkHttpHandler handler = new OkHttpHandler();

            String result = null;

            try {
                result = handler.execute(URL).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            outputText.append(result + "\n");
        }
    });
  }
}


public class OkHttpHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

public static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_CSV
        = MediaType.parse("text/csv; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

public OkHttpHandler(){

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String........params){

    String filename = "GPS_log2.csv";
    Log.d("doInBackground", "start");

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://160.16.84.183/php/uploadfile.php")
            .post(RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_CSV,filename))
            .build();

    try{
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if(!response.isSuccessful())
            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response.toString());
        return response.body().string();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Response ",e.getMessage());

    }
    return null;

}

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["upfile"]["tmp_name"])) {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upfile"]["tmp_name"], "/var/www/html/php/" . $_FILES["upfile"]["name"])) {
chmod("/var/www/html/php/" . $_FILES["upfile"]["name"], 0644);
echo $_FILES["upfile"]["name"] . "file uploaded";
} else {
echo "cannot file upload";
}
} else {
echo "do not choice file";
}
```

Comment: add complete code of uploadfile.php

Answer (score 1):

According to your PHP snippet, its seems to be ok. But the problem is your Android Code, because when ever your uploading data to server your request become multipart request, and your not mention'd the **upfile** attribute in the request how server will get that value if your not sending form client. The main problem what I understand is you have to send multipart request, instead of normal request.

For more details how to create Multipart request [click here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes)

```
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
            .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("upfile", file.getName(),
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/csv"), file))
            .addFormDataPart("field", "value")
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(serverURL)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.

I will sent only a file.
What can I set "value" and "field" for second sentence?

Comment: @aine then you can delete    .addFormDataPart("field", "value") this line. If you want to send any data to server along with the file then that will be helpful.

Comment: @aine, Welcome accept the solution by clicking on left side right mark, so that some one having the same problem they will easily solve the problem with out wasting their time.

Answer (score 1):

```
aine , you are trying to write file at /var/www/html/php/. it is not best practice to write files this location . Move your loaction of script to /home and change the path from etc/apache/siteenabled . For more details 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/379412/how-to-redirect-apache-var-www-to-the-home-directory-and-access-all-the-directo
For your PHP code must be as follows 
public static function processRequest()
{
    case 'post':
       if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"] , "Images/" . $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"] )){
                    echo "move_uploaded_file SUCCESS ";
    ......................................                
}
......................................           
protected function executePost ($ch)
{
    $tmpfile = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = basename($_FILES['image1']['name']);

    $data = array(
        'uploaded_file' => '@' . $tmpfile . ';filename='.$filename,
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);             
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
    //no need httpheaders
    $this->doExecute($ch); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I replace PHP code. but I cannot upload file.

Comment: what is your output comes ?